# How do I find the private or public key file that corresponds to a listing in `ssh-add -l`?

Tags: ssh

When I run the `ssh-add -l` command, I do not get any filenames. How do I find the filenames or otherwise find the origin of keys that are listed in `ssh-add -l`?

Here is the output I get:

```
~/.ssh ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:iQ2q8EE0sDPYp5icCTeXCi2iBWiqJEITqfnXRH1SOVA hqin@hqin-30jgh7.local (RSA)
2048 SHA256:nLrT5FirOWu3sDUvwS8ZWZq1TDy/VFCl+fcHzsf2AkQ  (RSA)
2048 SHA256:NdJXmNw7joMTSBwQG4OVY1kQLi8kagO1R1dKEvNzeYA  (RSA)
256 SHA256:lF1NWsr8K2wqOsbr94AJmRIRiJ/U/gDeZ7oZNz+jBDo hqin@hq6.local (ED25519)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since keys you seen n `ssh-add -l` can come from an agent or the local filesystem there isn't really any way to map the from the public key hashes back to the associated public or private keys.

You can use `ssh-add -L` to get the public key in the format that you might find in filesystem.

If all your keys in the current directory you could possibly run a command like this to report which filenames of the public keys that have been in your agent.  It seemed to mostly work for me at least.

```
$ grep -f <( ssh-add -L) *.pub -l
```